# Running multiple unlocked crew skill missions

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If I buy 3 level 500 missions on the GTN for, say, Diplomacy, can I run all 3 of those missions at once?

I know that if I unlock one to get a rare mission and try to unlock another before I send the first one out, I won't get 2 rare missions, I'll still only have one.

But if I send a companion out on a mission and then unlock another and send another companion out with the second mission and unlock a third and so on and so on, **would this work?**

Or does the game limit me to one rare mission at a time?

I'm too cheap to try it out and waste 30k on a mission.  Although I could try this with cheaper missions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only unlock and/or run one copy of each specific mission at a time.  Usually at each level there are 2-4 rare missions from discoveries for each skill.  At 500 Diplomacy, [there are 2](https://torcommunity.com/database/search/schematic/crew/diplomacy/catg/mission/sort/diff/order/desc/), so there is no way for you to run 3.  The mission discovery items should have different icons so that you can tell them apart.

Comment: Going to assume that one is light side and one is dark side.

Comment: @Vahx Yes, that's right.